# Como colocar uma imagem no title de um input

Tags: php, html, input

Olá, eu gostaria de colocar uma imagem com uma descrição no title(quando voce deixa o mouse em cima e aparece uma mensagem) de um input.

Comment: Para fazer isso você terá que usa algum pluguin javascript para fazer isso. recomendo que use http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers

Comment: É isto que procuras? -> http://jsfiddle.net/y8r3zpao/